# Fin the greatest lower bound for the set of all upper sums of the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}x, x \in Q \\ 0, x \notin Q \end{cases}, x \in [0, 1]$

Tags: calculus, integration

Some solutions that I saw use the partition $P= \left\{ 0, \frac1n, ... , \frac{n-1}{n}, n \right\}$ and show that the upper sum on the partition approaches $\frac12$ when $n \to \infty$. But how do we know that there is no partition of other form, the upper sum on which is less than $\frac12$?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly on what constitutes an upper sum, the function $f(x)=x$ is a sup on all intervals no matter how small because of the density of the rationals in the reals. And the integral of $x$ on $[0,1]$ is $\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @NinadMunshi how would a rigorous proof look? sup on each interval is f(x) for the largest rational x on this interval. I don't know what his rational is, and how do I tie it up with the integral of x?

Comment: Take any partition $P=\{x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$ of $[0,1]$ and then we have $U(P, f) =\sum_{k=1}^nM_k(x_k-x_{k-1})=\sum_{k=1}^nx_k(x_k-x_{k-1})$. Clearly this does not go less than $\int_0^1 x\, dx=1/2$ as it is also an upper sum for $g(x) =x$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: You need to understand why $M_k=x_k$ in last comment for each $k$. Also there is another approach which shows that if $P_n$ is a sequence of partitions whose norms tend to $0$ then $U(P_n, f) $ tends to infimum of all upper sums and hence using a partition as in your question is sufficient.

Comment: Right, it get it now. If $x_k$ were neither rational nor $sup(A) \mbox{ for } A=[f(x_{k-1}), f(x_k))$ then there would've been some $x \in [x_{k-1}, x_k)$,  such that $sup(A) \leq x < x_k$, but  there're rationals between $x$ and $x_k$, hence $x_k=sup(A)$